# displaying retrived data from SQL as table in android

Tags: android, gridview, tableview

I have some lists which containes data from the SQLServer. I want to display it in a single table in my android, which need 5 columns, how can i acheive this. what would be the besr method for doing this??
BTW i am a newbie in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Android ListView. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Example here :
http://techlovejump.com/android-multicolumn-listview/